# Unit testing validation with express-validator

Tags: node.js, validation, unit-testing, express

How can I unit test my validations that are done using express-validator?

I have tried creating a dummy request object, but I get the error: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'checkBody'`. I am able to manually test that the validation works in the application.

Here is what I have tried:

```
describe('couponModel', function () {
    it('returns errors when necessary fields are empty', function(done){
        var testBody = {
            merchant : '',
            startDate : '',
            endDate : ''
        };
        var request = {
            body : testBody
        };
        var errors = Model.validateCouponForm(request);
        errors.should.not.be.empty;
        done();
    });
});
```

My understanding is that the `checkBody` method is added to the request object when I have `app.use(expressValidator())` in my express application, but as I am only testing that the validation is working in this unit test I do not have an instance of the express application available, and the validation method that I am testing is not called directly from it anyway as it is only called through a post route, which I do not want to call for a unit test as it involves a database operation.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution for the new express-validator api (v4):

#### **tl;dr: You can use *this* function:**

```
exports.testExpressValidatorMiddleware = async (req, res, middlewares) => {
  await Promise.all(middlewares.map(async (middleware) => {
    await middleware(req, res, () => undefined);
  }));
};
```

**It can be called like *this*:**

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

await testExpressValidatorMiddleware(req, res, expressValidatorMiddlewareArray);
const result = validationResult(req);
expect(result....
```

These solutions assume you have the async/await syntax available. You can use the [node-mocks-http](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http) library to create the `req` and `res` objects.

### **Explanation:**

Each element in an express-validator array is applied to the route as middleware. Say this is your array:

```
[
  check('addresses.*.street').exists(),
  check('addresses.*.postalCode').isPostalCode(),
]
```

Each check will be loaded as middleware.

In order to test middleware, we need to implement a function which acts similarly to how express implements middleware.

Express middleware always accepts three params, the request and response objects, and the next function it should call (`next` by convention). Why do we need `next`? For scenarios where we want our middleware to do something before *and* after the proceeding function, e.g.

```
const loggerMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req body is ' + req.body);
  next();
  console.log('res status is ' + res.status);
};
```

But express-validator doesn't do this, it just calls `next()` once each of its validators is finished. For that reason, our implementation doesn't really need to bother with `next()`.

Instead, we can just run each of our middlewares in turn and pass an empty function as `next` to avoid a `TypeError`:

```
middlewares.map((middleware) => {
  middleware(req, res, () => undefined);
});
```

But this won't work, because express-validator middleware returns promises and we need to wait for them to resolve...

```
middlewares.map(async (middleware) => {
  await middleware(req, res, () => undefined);
});
```

And we don't want to move on until all promises in our iteration are resolved (Mozilla docs on `Promise.all` are [here](https://mdn.io/Promise.all)):

```
await Promise.all(middlewares.map(async (middleware) => {
  await middleware(req, res, () => undefined);
}));
```

And we should extract this as a reusable function:

```
exports.testExpressValidatorMiddleware = async (req, res, middlewares) => {
  await Promise.all(middlewares.map(async (middleware) => {
    await middleware(req, res, () => undefined);
  }));
};
```

And now we've arrived at my solution. If someone can improve on this implementation, I'm very happy to make edits.

Comment: do you by any chance know how to clear the `validationResult` ? Running in succession will keep appending errors to it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I had to create the methods using this:

```
var validRequest = {
  // Default validations used
  checkBody: function () { return this; },
  checkQuery: function () { return this; },
  notEmpty: function () { return this; },

  // Custom validations used
  isArray: function () { return this; },
  gte: function () { return this; },

  // Validation errors
  validationErrors: function () { return false; }
};

function getValidInputRequest(request) {
    Object.assign(request, validRequest);
    return request;
}
```

So, in your code you have to call the `getValidInputRequest` helper:

```
describe('couponModel', function () {
  it('returns errors when necessary fields are empty', function(done){
      var testBody = {
          merchant : '',
          startDate : '',
          endDate : ''
      };
      var request = {
          body : testBody
      };

      request = getValidInputRequest(request); // <-- Update the request

      var errors = Model.validateCouponForm(request);
      errors.should.not.be.empty;
      done();
  });
});
```

**Now, the `request` object has the `body` property and all the methods needed by express-validator.**

If you want to test the cases that the validator fails, you should use something like this:

```
function getInvalidInputRequest(request, errorParams) {
    // Get de default valid request
    Object.assign(request, validRequest);

    // Override the validationErrors function with desired errors
    request.validationErrors = function () {
        var errors = [];
        errorParams.forEach(function(error){
            errors.push({msg: 'the parameter "'+ error +'" is mandatory'})
        });
        return errors;
    };
    return request;
}
```

And to update the request you should do:

```
request = getInvalidInputRequest(request, ['mandatory_param_1', 'mandatory_param_2']);
```